# Displaying associative array in PHP session

Tags: javascript, php, xml

i have a sample book catalog which currently display the tittle and quantity of the book upon adding to cart.

However i would like to display the title, isbn number, quantity and total price of the book upon adding to cart.

The session variable was an associative array: title => Qty and i presume i would have to change it to a new associative array: title => array of [ISBN, Qty, Total]) but i couldn't wrap my head around it.

Below is a sample of the code.

The html page

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="CartPHP.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<img id="cover" src="test.jpg" />
<br />
<br />
<b>Book:</b><span id="book">name of book</span><br />
<b>Authors: </b><span id="authors"> Hart, Brandon, Jake</span>
<br /><b>ISBN: </b><span id="ISBN">0724583501</span>
<br /><b>Price: </b><span id="price">$39.99</span>
<br /><br />
<a href="#" onclick="AddRemoveItem('Add');" >Add to Shopping Cart</a>
<br /><br />
<span id="cart" ></span>
</body>
```

The javascript

```
function getData()
{
if ((xHRObject.readyState == 4) &&(xHRObject.status == 200))
{
    var serverResponse = xHRObject.responseXML;
    var header = serverResponse.getElementsByTagName("book");
    var spantag = document.getElementById("cart");
    spantag.innerHTML = "";
    for (i=0; i<header.length; i++)
    {

    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
         spantag.innerHTML += " " +header[0].firstChild.text;
         spantag.innerHTML += " " + header[0].lastChild.text + " " + "<a     href='#' onclick='AddRemoveItem(\"Remove\");'>Remove Item</a>";
    }
    else
    {
         spantag.innerHTML += " " +header[0].firstChild.textContent;
         spantag.innerHTML += " " + header[0].lastChild.textContent + " " +         "<a href='#' onclick='AddRemoveItem(\"Remove\");'>Remove Item</a>";
    }
   }
}
}

function AddRemoveItem(action)
{
      var book  = document.getElementById("book").innerHTML;

      if(action=="Add")
      {
        xHRObject.open("GET", "ManageCart.php?action=" + action + "&book=" +     encodeURIComponent(book) + "&value=" + Number(new Date), true);
      }
      else
      {
       xHRObject.open("GET", "ManageCart.php?action=" + action + "&book=" + encodeURIComponent(book) + "&value="  + Number(new Date), true);
      }

      xHRObject.onreadystatechange = getData;
      xHRObject.send(null);   
}
```

The Php

```
$newitem = $_GET["book"];
$action = $_GET["action"];
if ($_SESSION["Cart"] != "")
{
    $MDA = $_SESSION["Cart"];
    if ($action == "Add")
    {
        if ($MDA[$newitem] != "")
        {  
            $value = $MDA[$newitem] + 1;
            $MDA[$newitem] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $MDA[$newitem] = "1";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $MDA= "";
    }
}
else
{
    $MDA[$newitem] = "1";
}
$_SESSION["Cart"] = $MDA; 
ECHO (toXml($MDA));                                         

function toXml($MDA)
{
    $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
    $cart = $doc->createElement('cart');
    $cart = $doc->appendChild($cart);

    foreach ($MDA as $a => $b)
    {

    $book = $doc->createElement('book');
    $book = $cart->appendChild($book);

    $title = $doc->createElement('title'); 
    $title = $book->appendChild($title);   
    $value = $doc->createTextNode($a);
    $value = $title->appendChild($value);

    $quantity = $doc->createElement('quantity');
    $quantity = $book->appendChild($quantity);
    $value2 = $doc->createTextNode($b);
    $value2 = $quantity->appendChild($value2);

  }

    $strXml = $doc->saveXML(); 
    return $strXml;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If the variable $MDA is what you are trying to convert to an array as to assign it to the $_SESSION['cart'], You can append all the values of $MDA with a string like "|", and then explode it after the all the values have been appended to $MDA. 
Eg:

```
$append = "|";
$MDA .= "1".$append;
$MDA .= "3".$append;
$MDA .= "5";
//set to session
$_SESSION['cart'] = $MDA;
//then, when you want to get session values as an array
$sessionArrayValues = explode('|',$_SESSION['cart']);
```

Hope that helps...